# I don't know what‘s wrong with the Jupyter QtConsole

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, qtconsole

I used the anaconda python downloaded the Anaconda python3.x(32-bit) but when I
used jupyter QtConsole. I find built-in function  ‘help’ has some  problem.
For exmple when I typed  `help('modules')`  happend an error.``

[image]

Comment: Please paste the text of the exception into your question.  In this case, you'll also want to update the question to say how you installed Python and Jupyter, and what command line you used to start the window showing the error.  It appears to be from a 32-bit program installed on a 64-bit system (why not install 64-bit code?).

Comment: oh ,thanks for your advise，I update the question

Comment: oh ,thanks for your advise，I update the question

Comment: That looks like a bug, can you [open an issue](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues)?